# JAXB: unmarshal from XML subtree?

Tags: java, jaxb, gpx

My JAVA program uses an internal class hierarchy which resembles GPX 1.1, but is not identical. since rewriting it to conform 1:1 to GPX is a huge effort, I'd like to change it bit by bit, i.e. reading the `<metadata>` subtree into the Class `MetadataType` as generated with xjc from [the XSD file](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd)

the remaining GPX file is parsed with DOM, until `<metadata>` shows up:

```
private void parseMetadata(MetadataType metadata, Element element) throws JAXBException {
    try {
        System.out.println(element.getNodeName()); // output: metadata
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MetadataType.class);

        javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller u = context.createUnmarshaller();

        JAXBElement<MetadataType> meta = u.unmarshal(element, MetadataType.class);
        metadata = meta.getValue();

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println(metadata.getName()); // NULL
    System.out.println(metadata.getAuthor().getName()); // NULL
}
```

throws
`javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"metadata"). Expected elements are <{http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1}gpx>
    at  com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:647)`

the class looks like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "metadataType", propOrder = {
"name",
"desc",
"author",
"copyright",
"link",
"time",
"keywords",
"bounds",
"extensions"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "metadata")
public class MetadataType {

protected String name = "";
protected String desc = "";
protected PersonType author;
protected CopyrightType copyright = new CopyrightType();
protected List<LinkType> link = new ArrayList<LinkType>();
@XmlSchemaType(name = "Date")
protected Date time;
protected String keywords = "";
protected BoundsType bounds = new BoundsType();
protected ExtensionsType extensions = new ExtensionsType();
[...]
}
```

is it possible to unmarshal from an XML subtree; and if yes, what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE/1: 
thanks to lexicore, I'm a step further: `element` definitely contains the `metadata` node, `@XmlRootElement` is set, unmarshaling now with `unmarshal(element, MetadataType.class)`.

unmarshaling works, but the content of the objects is empty. I wonder if I run into some namespace troubles here?

the package `com.topografix.gpx._1._1` contains a package-info.java, generated by xjc:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.topografix.gpx._1._1;
```

here's one of the test files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" 
xmlns:gpxx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensions/v3" 
xmlns:wptx1="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1" 
xmlns:gpxtpx="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1" 
creator="GPSMAP 62s" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 
http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas /GpxExtensions/v3 
http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtension/v1 
http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/WaypointExtensionv1.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtension/v1 
http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrackPointExtensionv1.xsd">
<metadata>
<link href="http://www.garmin.com">
<text>Garmin International</text>
</link>
<time>2014-01-01T22:26:49Z</time>
</metadata>
[...]
```

UPDATE/2: the namespace/package name is right. If the namespace is set to (i.e.) "foobar", the following exception is thrown:
`javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory could not be instantiated: 
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "foobar" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index`

when initialized as before, the exception is not thrown, meaning that the namespace is correct AND the ObjectFactory.class is found.

`String contextPath = MetadataType.class.getPackage().getName();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(contextPath);`

So, the namespace is correct, but somehow the "link" to the MetadataType class is missing?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a few problems here:

- Your `MetadataType` does not have the `@XmlRootElement`. So JAXB does not know which element is supposed to match it.
- You want to unmarshal partially, but you're unmarshalling (I guess) the whole document.

What you could try:

- Try unmarshalling a specific class from the specific node using the [unmarshal(node, class)](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.2.4/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20java.lang.Class%29) method
- From your stack trace, you try to unmarshal `gpx:gpx` element, not the `metadata` element. You have to go deeper
- You have to overtake `package-info.java` as well (or provide namespaces in your `MetadataType`, otheriwse you're missing namespaces
- See this answer about [partial unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914628/partial-unmarshalling-with-jaxb).

Comment: thanks to your answer, I'm a step further now. question updated in this regard.

Comment: Yes, seems like ns issue. Try constructing your context with the package name instead of a single class.  I.e. JAXBContext.newInstance(MetadatatType.class.getPackage().getName()).

Comment: the namespace seems to be correct, but maybe the "link" to the class is not "found"? `@XmlRootElement` is set for MetadataType.class only

Comment: unmarshal(node, class) method, worked for me !