# Unable to unmarshal the XML to my class using the XMLEventReader

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, stax

I am trying to perform `JAXB Unmarshalling` for a large `XML` file so using the `XMLEventReader` but it's not working as expected and not performing the `Unmarshalling`.

Following is the XML file that I am trying to `unmarshal`:

```
<Customers>
  <Customer>
    <name>BATMAN</name>
    <age>2008</age>
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <name>SuperMan</name>
    <age>2022</age>
  </Customer>
</Customers>
```

Following is the `Customer.class` which will be used for `unmarshalling`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private String age;
}
```

Following is the `Main` class which will `unmarshal` each of the `customer` and store in the `customer` field but it returns null. Normally when I would expect it to print me the customer information.

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {
    final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLEventReader streamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    while (streamReader.hasNext()) {
      final XMLEvent e = streamReader.nextEvent();

      if (e.isStartElement() && ((StartElement) e).getName().getLocalPart().equals("Customer")) {
        System.out.println(((StartElement) e).getName().getLocalPart());
        final Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streamReader, Customer.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(customer);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried with the `XMLStreamReader` and it works perfectly. But I want to make use of `XMLEventReader peak()` functionality. Hence, I am trying to make use of `XMLEventReader`.
I looked at many examples and they provided similar examples not sure what's going wrong in my case.

Can someone please help me in understanding the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying few things I was able to get it working. Posting the answer here so it can be useful to someone in the future:

```
class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, JsonProcessingException {
    final InputStream inputStream = Main.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Customer.xml");
    final XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    final XMLEventReader xmlEventReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLEventReader(inputStream);
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    while (xmlEventReader.peek() != null) {
      XMLEvent event = xmlEventReader.peek();

      if (event.isStartElement() && ((StartElement) event).getName().getLocalPart().equals("Customer")) {
        Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlEventReader, Customer.class).getValue();
        System.out.println("Normal Customer : " + customer);
      } else {
        xmlEventReader.next();
      }
    }
  }
}
```